# d3 js redraw graph add existing nodes again

Tags: d3.js

Trying to add new nodes to existing graph with `add` function end up with all new graph. here is my [code](https://github.com/itayB/d3-graph/blob/master/index.js):

```
function Graph(elementId) {
    var svg;
    var simulation;
    var mNodesData = [];
    var mEdgesData = [];
    var mNode = null;
    var mLink = null;
    var elementId;
    var heightDelta = 100;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight - heightDelta;

    return {
        init: function () {
            svg = d3.select('#' + elementId)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force(".edge", d3.forceLink())
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-600))
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
        },
        clearGraph: function () {
            $('#' + this.elementId).empty();
        },
        getNodes: function () {
            return mNodesData;
        },
        getEdges: function () {
            return mEdgesData;
        },
        addNodes: function (nodes) {
            mNodesData = mNodesData.concat(nodes);
        },
        addEdges: function (edges) {
            mEdgesData = mEdgesData.concat(edges);
        },
        draw: function () {
            mLink = svg.selectAll(".edge")
                .data(mEdgesData)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "edge")
                .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                .style("stroke-width", function (e) {
                    return 1
                    /* e.width*/
                });

            mNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(mNodesData)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));

            mNode.on('mouseover', function (d) {
                function removePopup() {
                    $("#nodePopup").remove();
                }

                function showPopup(d) {
                    removePopup();
                    if (!d['data']) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var data = d['data'];
                    var htmlStr = '';
                    htmlStr += '<div id="nodePopup" >';
                    htmlStr += '    <div><button id="nodePopupCloseButton" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: 13px;"> </span> </div>';
                    htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupName">' + data['name'] + '</div>';
                    if (data['desc']) {
                        if (data['desc'].startsWith("http")) {
                            htmlStr += '    <a class="nodePopupLink" href="' + data['desc'] + '" target="_blank">Go to post..</a>';
                        }
                        else {
                            htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupDesc">' + data['desc'] + '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                    htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupGroup">GROUP: ' + data['groupId'] + '</div>';
                    htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupLeader">LEADER: ' + data['leaderId'] + '</div>';
                    htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupImage"><img src="' + d['image'] + '" style="width: 130px;" /></div>';
                    htmlStr += '</div>';

                    $("body").append(htmlStr);
                    $("#nodePopupCloseButton").click(removePopup);
                }

                showPopup(d);

                mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                    return (d !== d1 && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
                }).select("image").style("opacity", 0.2);
                mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                    return (d !== d1 && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
                }).select("circle").style("stroke", "#f6f6f6");
                mLink.filter(function (d1) {
                    return (d !== d1.source && d !== d1.target);
                }).style("opacity", 0.2);

                mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                    return (d == d1 || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
                }).select("image").style("opacity", 1);
                mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                    return (d == d1 || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
                }).select("circle").style("stroke", "gray");
                mLink.filter(function (d1) {
                    return (d == d1.source || d == d1.target);
                }).style("opacity", 1);
            })
                .on('mouseout', function () {
                    // removePopup();
                    mNode.select("image").style("opacity", 1);
                    mNode.select("circle").style("stroke", "gray");
                    mLink.style("opacity", 1);
                });

            var nodeCircle = mNode.append("circle")
                .attr("r", function (d) {
                    return 0.5 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)
                })
                .attr("stroke", "gray")
                .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
                .attr("fill", "white");

            var nodeImage = mNode.append("image")
                .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                    return d.image
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return d.height + ""
                })
                .attr("width", function (d) {
                    return d.width + ""
                })
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return -0.5 * d.width
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return -0.5 * d.height
                })
                .attr("clip-path", function (d) {
                    return "circle(" + (0.48 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)) + "px)"
                });


            simulation.nodes(mNodesData);
            simulation.force(".edge").links(mEdgesData);

            simulation.on("tick", function () {
                mLink.attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                    .attr("y1", function (d) {
                        return d.source.y;
                    })
                    .attr("x2", function (d) {
                        return d.target.x;
                    })
                    .attr("y2", function (d) {
                        return d.target.y;
                    })

                mNode.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
                });
                mNode.attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d.x = Math.max(d.width, Math.min(width - d.width, d.x));
                })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) {
                        return d.y = Math.max(d.height, Math.min(height - heightDelta - d.height, d.y));
                    });
            });

            function dragstarted(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(d) {
                d.fx = d3.event.x;
                d.fy = d3.event.y;
            }

            function dragended(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'api/v1/data.json',
        type: "GET",
    });
}

var graph = Graph('d3Graph');
graph.init();

$.when(getData()).then(function (data) {
    graph.addNodes(data.nodes);
    graph.addEdges(data.edges);
    graph.draw();

});


function add() {
    graph.addNodes([{
        "id": 4,
        "image": "images/4.jpeg",
        "height": 20,
        "width": 20,
        "adjacents": [0],
        "data": {
            "name": "Number4",
            "groupId": "Bla4",
            "desc": "Desc4",
            "leaderId": "1234-1234"
        }
    }]);
    graph.addEdges([{
        "source": 4,
        "target": 3,
        "width": 1
    }])
    graph.draw();
    // graph.draw();
}
```

if i call to `add` the original graph stack on the page and a new one with another edge & node is added. How do I achieve that correct? (update the old one without creating all new..

Comment: can you post a working fiddle

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do it with the ajax request and the static files. I've added link to my github repo, can you please try to clone it and run locally? I'll try to figure how to do it meanwhile..

Comment: hey you can use gist to put your sample JSON. Then ajax it. Here is a small sample on how to do it https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-L0IvrLD7ffULnFx-XAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `merge` to both links & nodes:

```
mLink = svg.selectAll(".edge")
                .data(mEdgesData)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("class", "edge")
                .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                .style("stroke-width", function (e) {
                    return 1
                    /* e.width*/
                }).merge(mLink);

            mNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(mNodesData)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node").merge(mNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have:

```
 mLink = svg.selectAll("link")
            .data(mEdgesData)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
```

Normally `selectAll("link")` means that you select all html elements which are links. But you append a `line` and not a `link`.  Therefore the appended element is not part of your `selectAll`. There is no possibility to know that you just wanna add data to something which already exists.

Comment: I tried to change line to link, now no egde appears, only nodes. It happens on the first load, even before trying to add..

Comment: You want to draw a line. What you can do is:
`selectAll(".edge")` and then after `.append("line")` you do `.attr("class", "edge")`

Comment: I did it, and did the same for the node. now in `add` only one new link and one new node added to view, but the first 4 nodes became inactive (I cannot drag them anymore)

Comment: Can you make an edit to your question with the new code section?

Comment: can you try `mNode.call...` like adding `mNode.` to the `call` line. I'm not sure whether this makes a difference though. I'm not an expert in d3 :D

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to create a general update procedure for my graph with dynamic data. When the nodes or links where updated, the `redraw` function was triggered.

The idea works as follows; on redrawing the graph, i.e. when the data has changed, all old nodes and links are removed and drawn again. Using `.join()` the nodes remain in their position.

Here is my **working example**:

```js
redraw = () => {
    simulation.nodes(nodes);
    simulation.force('link')
        .links(links)
        .initialize(nodes);

    d3.selectAll('g.node').remove(); // remove all old nodes
    d3.selectAll('g.node').data(nodes).join();
    d3.selectAll("line").data(links).join();

    draw();

    simulation.alpha(0.1)
    simulation.restart();
}
```

In my `draw()` function, the nodes and links are created accordingly:

```js
draw = () => {
    container.selectAll('line').data(links).join('line');

    // creates nodes with rectangles that contain text
    container.selectAll('g.node').raise()
        .data(nodes).join("g")
        .each(function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).append("rect");
            var text = d3.select(this).append("text").text(d => d.name)

            // calculate text width for function tick() to adapt rect x position
            d.width = text.filter(t => t.index == d.index).node()
                          .getBBox().width; 
        })
        .call(drag(simulation));
}
```

Where `container` is a zoomable and draggable SVG element:

```js
container = svg.append('g');
svg.call(d3.zoom()
   .on('zoom', () => this.container.attr('transform', d3.event.transform))
   .scaleExtent([0.25, 2]))
```

For completeness, here is my `tick()` function:

```js
tick = () => {
    container.selectAll('rect')
        .attr('x', d => d.x - d.width / 2)
        .attr('y', d => d.y);

    container.selectAll('text')
        .attr('x', d => d.x - d.width / 2)
        .attr('y', d => d.y);

    container.selectAll('line')
        .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);
}
```

If I have time, I post a JSFiddle later.